# OpsHub User Mapping Error

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I'm using the OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration tool to migrate a TFS2010 project (source code only) to Visual Studio online. On the user mapping screen, I made my mappings (most to anonymous, but a few key users with mappings) and off it went. After a while I got the following:

```
249/410 Changeset(s)/Label(s) passed
1/410 Changeset(s)/Label(s) pending for retry
```

When I view the errors, I see this:

```
OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF14045: The identity XYZ, Bruce (USHQ) is not a recognized identity.
```

Bruce is one of the users I mapped. I went back in to update the migration to see what I can do.

I tried removing the "XYZ, Bruce (USHQ) -- XYZ, Bruce (USHQ)" mapping and re-adding it and then retrying. Same error.

I then tried removing the mapping and mapping to anonymous. It seemed to accept this, but got the same error on retry. I noticed then that the mapping was back to "XYZ, Bruce (USHQ) -- XYZ, Bruce (USHQ)" and I can't seem to make it anonymous. This is true for any users that appear in both lists (TFS Users and VSO users).

Other users are mapping correctly from what I can tell.

My best case would be to correctly map this user. Next would be to map it to anonymous.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Below is the error in the log:

```
2015-06-09 07:51:56,022 [3] ERROR Error occured in thread of CheckinAll:TF14045: The identity XYZ, Bruce (USHQ) is not a recognized identity.
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.HandleReply(TfsClientOperation operation, TfsMessage message, Object[]& outputs)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Repository5.CheckIn(String workspaceName, String ownerName, String[] serverItems, Changeset info, CheckinNotificationInfo checkinNotificationInfo, Int32 checkinOptions, Failure[]& conflicts, Failure[]& failures, Boolean deferCheckIn, Int32 checkInTicket, Int32 maxClientPathLength)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.WebServiceLayerLocalWorkspaces.CheckIn(String workspaceName, String ownerName, String[] serverItems, Changeset info, CheckinNotificationInfo checkinNotificationInfo, Int32 checkinOptions, UploadedBaselinesCollection uploadedBaselinesCollection, Failure[]& conflicts, Failure[]& failures, Boolean deferCheckIn, Int32 checkInTicket)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.PagedCheckin(IEnumerable`1 changes, Boolean changesIsAllPendingChanges, Changeset changeset, CheckinNotificationInfo checkinNotificationInfo, CheckInOptions2 checkinOptions, UploadedBaselinesCollection uploadedBaselinesCollection, Failure[]& conflictsArray, Failure[]& failuresArray)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckInInternal(WorkspaceCheckInParameters parameters, Int32 operationId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace.CheckIn(WorkspaceCheckInParameters checkinParameters)
   at Service.Adapters.TFSCheckinWorkspaceContext.checkin(String comment, WorkItemCheckinInfo[] workItemChanges, List`1 otherCheckInProperties, String checkinUser) in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUOpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSVersionControl\AdapterComponents\TFSCheckinWorkspaceContext.cs:line 2579
   at Service.Adapters.TFSVCAdapter.checkIn(List`1 checkinItems, String checkinComment, String checkinUser, List`1 workitemId, List`1 otherCheckInProperties) in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUOpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSVersionControl\AdapterComponents\TFSVCAdapter.cs:line 125
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CheckInAll>b__0() in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUOpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line 760
2015-06-09 07:51:56,024 [3] ERROR Error : TF14045: The identity XYZ, Bruce (USHQ) is not a recognized identity.
```

Comment: Hi, how were the users of VSO created? I think the issue it towards the user in VSO. Maybe an access issue.

Comment: Users were added to VSO using the Users Assign licenses screen. I clicked "Add" and the typed their name where is says "Select User from Directory". VSO is linked to our Azure AD so when I type a name, it shoes up in the drop down.

Comment: Any thoughts? Thanks! #opshub

Comment: Hi, I think the issue could be towards access. Is there any way you can confirm, Bruce (USHQ) of VSO can access to repository? Or has check-in permissions? We also use impersonation (through the user by which the VSO end point was created in the utility), so you might also need check the 'Allow changes on behalf of other user' permision.